# Laravel 8 & Jetstream - Register Form with Two button, a button for autocomplete Fiscal Code and one for Submit data

Tags: php, laravel, registration, laravel-8, user-registration

I'm try to create my first custom register module in **Jetstream** on **Laravel 8** and i've create **6 important custom fields** to generate automatically the **Italian fiscal code** (name, surname, gender, birthday, birthday_province, birthplace )
After these i've implemented this repo to generate automatically the fiscal code:
[https://github.com/lucavandro/CodiceFiscaleJS#:~:text=CodiceFiscale.js%20is%20a%20javascript%20and%20typescript%20utility%20library,and%20validate%20Italian%20Italian%20Tax%20code%20%28codice%20fiscale%29](https://github.com/lucavandro/CodiceFiscaleJS#:%7E:text=CodiceFiscale.js%20is%20a%20javascript%20and%20typescript%20utility%20library,and%20validate%20Italian%20Italian%20Tax%20code%20%28codice%20fiscale%29).

The problem that i have now is that i have one button for generate the fiscal code and a button to submit all form to create a new user in the same form

So how can i active the first button to autofill the input without refresh the page and after this click on the second button to complete the registration?

```
<x-guest-layout>
    <x-jet-authentication-card>
        <x-slot name="logo">
            <x-jet-authentication-card-logo />
        </x-slot>

        <x-jet-validation-errors class="mb-4" />

        <form method="POST" action="{{ route('register') }}">
            @csrf

            <div>
                <x-jet-label for="name" value="{{ __('Nome') }}" />
                <x-jet-input id="name" class="block mt-1 w-full" type="text" name="name" :value="old('name')" required
                    autofocus autocomplete="name" />
            </div>

            <!-- Creo un campo cognome -->
            <div>
                <x-jet-label for="surname" value="{{ __('Cognome') }}" />
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="surname" name="surname" :value="old('surname')" required>
            </div>

            <div class="mt-4">
                <x-jet-label for="email" value="{{ __('Email') }}" />
                <x-jet-input id="email" class="block mt-1 w-full" type="email" name="email" :value="old('email')"
                    required />
            </div>

            <!-- Add the nickname to default settings, dopo modifica la migration "create user" -->
            <div class="mt-4">
                <x-jet-label for="nickname" value="{{ __('Nickname') }}" />
                <x-jet-input id="nickname" class="block mt-1 w-full" type="text" name="nickname"
                    :value="old('nickname')" required />
            </div>

            <!-- Creo una select per il sesso -->
            <div class="mt-4">
                <x-jet-label for="gender" value="{{ __('Sesso') }}" />
                <select id="gender" class="block mt-1 w-full" type="select" name="gender" :value="old('gender')" required>
                    <option value="M">Maschio</option> <!-- Viene salvato il value -->
                    <option value="F">Femmina</option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <!-- Creo un input per la data di nascita -->
            <div class="mt-4">
                <x-jet-label for="birthday" value="{{ __('Anno di nascita') }}" />
                <input id="birthday" class="form-control" type="date"  name="birthday" :value="old('birthday')" required>
            </div>

            <!-- Creo una select per la provincia di nascita -->
            <div class="mt-4">
                <x-jet-label for="birthday_province" value="{{ __('Provincia di nascita') }}" />
                <select class="custom-select" name="birthplace_province" id="birthplace_province" required>
                </select>
            </div>

            <!-- Creo una select per il comune di nascita -->
            <div class="mt-4">
                <x-jet-label for="birthplace" value="{{ __('Comune di nascita') }}" />
                <select class="custom-select" name="birthplace" id="birthplace" required>
                </select>
            </div>

            <!-- Creo un input per la generazione automatica del codice fiscale -->
            <div class="mt-4">
                <x-jet-label for="cf" value="{{ __('Codice Fiscale') }}" />
                <input type="text" class="input-auto" name="cf" id="cf-1" readonly>
                <button type="submit" class="btn-inline" >Genera Codice Fiscale</button>
            </div>

            <div class="mt-4">
                <x-jet-label for="password" value="{{ __('Password') }}" />
                <x-jet-input id="password" class="block mt-1 w-full" type="password" name="password" required
                    autocomplete="new-password" />
            </div>

            <div class="mt-4">
                <x-jet-label for="password_confirmation" value="{{ __('Confirm Password') }}" />
                <x-jet-input id="password_confirmation" class="block mt-1 w-full" type="password"
                    name="password_confirmation" required autocomplete="new-password" />
            </div>

            @if (Laravel\Jetstream\Jetstream::hasTermsAndPrivacyPolicyFeature())
            <div class="mt-4">
                <x-jet-label for="terms">
                    <div class="flex items-center">
                        <x-jet-checkbox name="terms" id="terms" />

                        <div class="ml-2">
                            {!! __('I agree to the :terms_of_service and :privacy_policy', [
                            'terms_of_service' => '<a target="_blank" href="'.route('terms.show').'"
                                class="underline text-sm text-gray-600 hover:text-gray-900">'.__('Terms of
                                Service').'</a>',
                            'privacy_policy' => '<a target="_blank" href="'.route('policy.show').'"
                                class="underline text-sm text-gray-600 hover:text-gray-900">'.__('Privacy
                                Policy').'</a>',
                            ]) !!}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </x-jet-label>
            </div>
            @endif

            <div class="flex items-center justify-end mt-4">
                <a class="underline text-sm text-gray-600 hover:text-gray-900" href="{{ route('login') }}">
                    {{ __('Ho già un account?') }}
                </a>

                <x-jet-button class="ml-4">
                    {{ __('Registrati') }}
                </x-jet-button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </x-jet-authentication-card>
</x-guest-layout>
```